# Overscroll header/footer for ScrollView?

Tags: android, listview, android-widget, scrollview

ListView has this nice feature where you can set an overscroll header or footer. ScrollView, unfortunately, has no such thing. Does anyone know of a way to put together something that works like a ScrollView with an overscroll header/footer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess is you might be able to accomplish this with a similar approach as pull-to-refresh for lists is implemented on Android devices: you basically stretch a view at the top of (probably actually above - same for a 'footer', but then below) the ScrollView to fake an overscroll effect.

For some ideas on this, have a look at this [pull-to-refresh implementation](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh/blob/master/pulltorefresh/src/com/markupartist/android/widget/PullToRefreshListView.java). It dynamically adjusts the padding of a header view in the list to simulate it being overscrolled when 'pulling'.

Comment: This is interesting. I need to study the code a bit to see if it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you put your ScrollView inside a RelativeLayout, which will also contain the header and footer? Something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:alignParentTop="true"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/scroller"
        android:alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In this question ( [Can we use a ScrollView inside a LinearLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938303/cant-we-use-scroll-view-inside-linearlayout) ), someone showed how to put a ScrollView inside a LinearLayout. It should be the same.

Comment: That would make the header and footer visible all the time, which isn't the behavior I'm looking for. ListView's overscroll header/footer only come onto the screen when the list is overscrolled.