# android layout with automatic scrollview

Tags: android

i have in my android main.xml file as the following.. 
when i run it is showing some exception but in main.xml in graphical view it is not showing any error..
follwing is my code inside Linearlayout

```
      <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">       

              <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"
                       android:text="UserName"/>

               <EditText android:id="@+id/username"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:text=""/>                              
           <Button
               android:id="@+id/login_button"
               android:layout_width="60dp"
               android:layout_height="30dp"
               android:text="login"/>
        </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">       

              <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"
                       android:text=""/>

               <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:text=""/>                              
           <Button
               android:layout_width="60dp"
               android:layout_height="30dp"
               android:text="@string/login_btn"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScrollView should have ONLY ONE child. in ur example u have placed 2 linear layouts inside scrollview which is causing error..
   place the 2 linear layouts inside 1 linear layout and place the whole thing in scrollview. it will work..

```
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
             <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">  
                      <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">       

                          <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                   android:layout_gravity="center"
                                   android:text="@string/UserNameText"/>

                           <EditText
                                   android:id="@+id/username"
                                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                   android:text="@string/UserNameText"/>                              
                       <Button
                           android:id="@+id/login_button"
                           android:layout_width="60dp"
                           android:layout_height="30dp"
                           android:text="@string/login_btn"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                     <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">       

                          <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                   android:layout_gravity="center"
                                   android:text="@string/UserNameText"/>

                           <EditText
                                   android:id="@+id/username"
                                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                   android:text="@string/UserNameText"/>                              
                       <Button
                           android:id="@+id/login_button"
                           android:layout_width="60dp"
                           android:layout_height="30dp"
                           android:text="@string/login_btn"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: You still need to change the child views height. They can't both be `match_parent` and should never be set to that in a ScrollView. They should be `wrap_content`

Answer (score 2):

`ScrollView` should have **ONLY ONE** child.

Answer (score 1):

ScrollViews can only contain a single child view. Wrap your two LinearLayouts in another LinearLayout.

You also have both linear layouts height set to `match_parent`. This won't work in a scrollview. They should both be set to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 1):

try this xml for your problem

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
   <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">       

              <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"
                       android:text="UserName"/>

               <EditText android:id="@+id/username"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:text=""/>                              
           <Button
               android:id="@+id/login_button"
               android:layout_width="60dp"
               android:layout_height="30dp"
               android:text="login"/>
        </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">       

              <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"
                       android:text=""/>

               <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:text=""/>                              
           <Button
               android:layout_width="60dp"
               android:layout_height="30dp"
               android:text="@string/login_btn"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for more detail click this link [Can we use a ScrollView inside a LinearLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938303/cant-we-use-scroll-view-inside-linearlayout)

Comment: That won't work. The LinearLayout needs to be inside the Scrollview and not outside it. And the child LinearLayouts can't have the height set to `match_parent`

Answer (score 1):

**Scroll View can have only One Direct child..**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="UserName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="login" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="@string/login_btn" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>  </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView should have only one child.