# Make layout scrollable

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

[image]

I want to make the given layout scrollable, so that the two buttons are fixed and the 4 imageViews can be scrolled. I tried the following code, but it messed up..kindly, help

Layout :

```
     <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >
      <ScrollView 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >

<RelativeLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/no_media" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/no_media" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/no_media" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv3"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/no_media" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Click on the four images to take the pic" />

      </RelativeLayout>

 </ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Button" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938303/can-we-use-a-scrollview-inside-a-linearlayout Take a look at this question. It is very simililar to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take this code dude :) best of luck

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rel" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/iv1"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv3"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:text="Click on the four images to take the pic" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Click on the four images to take the pic" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

put fillviewport inside scrollview like this:

```
 <ScrollView 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:fillViewport="true"
  >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ScrollView 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >

<RelativeLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/no_media" />.....
```

Just remove RelativeLayout and put images directly into ScrollVIew